# Convert custome Key+Value JSON object Response to C# Model

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamics-crm, key-value, reflection.emit

i have this API that i want to creat a **dynamic object.** My point here is to have normal object to deal with rather than what this API returns to me, i can't controll this API so the retrived data can't be modified, this is the body, and it represnet a view in Database

Also i think reflection could help me in this case, any idea....

Request Body:

```
{
    "ViewName": "Person",
    "ViewOutput": "Name, Email, Number",
    "ViewFilter": [
        {
            "filterKey": "Number",
            "filterValue": "532000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the ViewName + ViewOutput+ ViewFilter to be paramterized,
ViewName it will take single value,
ViewOutput will be array of string
ViewFilter will be list of filteration ("FilterKey", "FilterVlaue") because it could be mutliple filteration value like this:

```
"ViewFilter": [
        {
            "filterKey": "Number",
            "filterValue": "532000000"
        },
        {
            "filterKey": "Email",
            "filterValue": "test1@test.ps"
        }
    ]
```

This is What API Return to me, a list of Person Keys and values,

Response:

```
{
    "ResponseCode": "0",
    "ResponseMessage": "Success",
    "NumberOfRecords": "1",
    "MainData": [
        {
            "recordData": [
                {
                    "dataKey": "Name",
                    "dataValue": "Test Name"
                },
                {
                    "dataKey": "Email",
                    "dataValue": "test@test.ps"
                },
                {
                    "dataKey": "Number",
                    "dataValue": "532000000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What i want to be the output is like this:

```
"Person": [
{
    "Name":"Test",
    "Email":"test@test.ps",
    "Number":"532000000",
}]
```

Comment: Hi guys, i here reflection could help me in this, is anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the response JSON into an empty class file in Visual Studio using the [Paste JSON As Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC0Lw.png) feature, yields these classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfRecords { get; set; }
    public Maindata[] MainData { get; set; }
}

public class Maindata
{
    public Recorddata[] recordData { get; set; }
}

public class Recorddata
{
    public string dataKey { get; set; }
    public string dataValue { get; set; }
}
```

You can create your own `Person` class.

Once you deserialize the JSON into the generated classes, one way to get a `List<Person>` would be to do something like this (please note that this is untested example code):

```
var people = rootObject.Maindata.Select(r => 
    {
        var name = r.recordData.Single(d => d.dataKey == "Name").dataValue;
        var email = r.recordData.Single(d => d.dataKey == "Email").dataValue;
        var number = r.recordData.Single(d => d.dataKey == "Number").dataValue;
        return new Person(name, email, number);     
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Aron, this what i literally do.

but what i facing right now is Views from this type are increasing and every database View have different inner property.

the Person model here is an example, but in real i have complex data and structures